# UIScrollView resets contentSize

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, contentsize

Why does a `UIScrollView` instance reset its contentSize (in my case to the frame, and screen, width) by the time the delegate `scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *) aScrollView withView:(UIView *) aView atScale:(float) aScale` gets called?

What should I do about this? For example, do I really need to remind the instance of its `contentSize`, perhaps in the `layoutSubviews` method?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing.  Solution?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the delegate method you are looking for is

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

It tells the delegate that the scroll view’s zoom factor changed.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html